# Sieve Of Sundaram

Tags: vba, excel, primes, prime-factoring

I'm need someone to walk me through the Sieve of Sundaram ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram)). Lets say I have a list of Integers, *(41,43,47,49,51,53,59)* in an array.

Now the above mentioned wikipedia explanation mentions: *

> An odd integer is excluded from the final list if and only if it is of
>   the form 2(i+j+2ij)+1

*. I am trying to understand how to achieve this in a program *(preferably VBA)*. Such that the output will be *(41,43,47,53,59)*.

Explanations sincerely appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: do your own homework. if you have some actual code and need help with specific parts of it, then feel free to post the code here and ask that specific question. but right now you're just looking for someone to do your homework for you

Comment: I agree with Marc here. A simple google search `Sieve of Sundaram in vba` will give you so many examples ;)

Comment: Thanks Marc B and Siddharth Rout.  The last line reads 'explanations' not 'actual code'. :(  And regarding the simple google search, well it doesnt give me 'so many examples'. :(

Answer (score 1):

I discuss the Sieve of Sundaram at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/10/07/sieve-of-sundaram/). The algorithm is given by the following pseudocode:

```
function sundaram(n)
    m := n // 2
    sieve := makeArray(m+1, True)
    for i from 1 to m // 4
        for j from i to (m-i) // (2*i+1)
            sieve[i+j+2*i*j] := False
    ps := [2]
    for i from 1 to m
        if sieve[i]
            append 2*i+1 to ps
    return ps
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply user448810. Could you explain the sieve itself (in normal english), so that I can design my own implementation of it?  In the meanwhile, I will definitely be studying the code you have shared and visiting your blog too. Regards

Answer (score 0):

As per the WP article, after removing some numbers from a range `k=1...n`, we get the results as `m=2k+1`. That means that all `m`s are odd.

Now, an odd composite must be a product of two odd numbers: `2k+1 = (2i+1)(2j+1) = 4ij+2i+2j+1` (if one of them were even, the product would be even too). But that means that `k = 2ij + i + j`. Hence the sieve's operation.

As nicely explained [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A0%25D0%25B5%25D1%2588%25D0%25B5%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE_%25D0%25A1%25D1%2583%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B0%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B0).